# how can i upload large file with .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, chunks

i'm trying to do chunk uplod for large file so i slice the file and send each slice in request.
i send the chunk and the chunk number and total chank number withrequest with XmlHttpRequest  to the controller.
but in the method on controller i c'ant acces to the chunk index or the total chunk il always 0 .

```
 [HttpPost]
        public string UploadChunks( int CHUNK_INDEX, int TOTAL_CHUNK)
        {
            
            var chunks = Request.Body;
           
            string path = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, @"file\temp");
            string newpath = Path.Combine(path, Guid.NewGuid()+".tmp"+CHUNK_INDEX.ToString());
            
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(newpath))
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[775700];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = chunks.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }


            return "succes" ;
        }
```

the js function

```
 function upload(file) {
            var blob = file;
            var BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 775700; 
            var SIZE = file.size;               
            var start = 0;
            var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
            var completed = 0;
            var count = SIZE % BYTES_PER_CHUNK == 0 ? SIZE / BYTES_PER_CHUNK : Math.floor(SIZE / BYTES_PER_CHUNK) + 1;
            var index = 1;
            while (start < SIZE) {
                var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);
                
                var data = new FormData();
                data.append("TOTAL_CHUNK", count);
                data.append("CHUNK_INDEX", index++);
                data.append("CHUNK", chunk);

               var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "UploadChunks", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                xhr.send(data);

               /* fetch("/UploadFile/MultiUpload", {
                    method: 'post',
                    body: data
                });*/
                   
                start = end
                end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your js like below:

```
while (start < SIZE) {
    index++;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "UploadChunks", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  
    xhr.send("TOTAL_CHUNK=" + count + "&CHUNK_INDEX=" + index);   
}
```